# How to pass custom requests into Interface class?

Tags: php, laravel

Making Interface class for Crud operations I need in some cases to pass custom requests
in app/Repositories/Interfaces/CrudInterface.php I have :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

interface CrudInterface
{
    public function store(array $data, FormRequest $request): Model;
    ...
```

But when in implementation of this class app/Repositories/TagCrudRepository.php I pass CreateTagRequest as parameter :

```
<?php
namespace App\Repositories;

use App\Http\Requests\CreateTagRequest;

use App\Repositories\Interfaces\CrudInterface;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
...
use App\Library\TagsSearchResultsIterator;

class TagCrudRepository implements CrudInterface
{

    public function store(array $data, CreateTagRequest $request): Tag
    {
        ...
```

I got error :

```
 Declaration of App\Repositories\TagCrudRepository::store(array $data, App\Http\Requests\CreateTagRequest $request): App\Models\Tag must be compatible with App\Repositories\Interfaces\CrudInterface::store(array $data, Illuminate\Foundat
  ion\Http\FormRequest $request): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
```

class app/Http/Requests/CreateTagRequest.php extends extends FormRequest class:

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class CreateTagRequest extends FormRequest
{
```

How this error can be fixed ?

Comment: Why not use a common interface for all requests?

Comment: That is just what I did CrudInterface which I used  for all requests. Could, you please detalize your remark ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **pass** instance of `CreateTagRequesta` at runtime w/o any problems though because it extends `FormRequest` but method signature must match what interface (contract) defines. If you need to ensure that this particular `store()` implementation gets instance of `CreateTagRequest` and not `FormRequest`, then you either need to change the interface or create another method. There's no other way.

Comment: How can I pass instance of CreateTagRequesta at runtime ?

as I have defined CreateTagRequesta in function definition :
    public function store(array $data, CreateTagRequest $request): Tag
?

Comment: by OOP principle you can pass child class to any methods requiring parent class and that should be fine.  If your `store()` implementaion does not need anything from handed object that is added by `CreateTagRequesta`, then passing instance of  `FormRequest` or **any** subclass of it (no matter how distant) should be equivalent. So i.e. `store([], new CreateTagRequest(...))` should work as good as `store([], new FormRequest(...))`;

Comment: I try to follow your message and failed. Please read : Invalid Fixes:

Comment: do not edit your question with follow up problems. Your original question was about inheritance, not null argument value. If you got another problem, please post another question. If your inheritance problem is solved, please mark answer accepted